# How to rename n files with ANT? (Batch Job)

Tags: java, ant, batch-processing

How can I rename 1..n file with ANT? I would like to rename any files with `xxxx.default.properties` to `xxxx.local.properties`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using the [move](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) task you could do something like this:

```
  <move todir="my/src/dir" includeemptydirs="false">
    <fileset dir="my/src/dir"/>
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.default.properties" to="*.local.properties"/>
  </move>
```

Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: Can we use Regular Expression in from and to ?

Comment: @unkwn yes. you can use a [regexmapper](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [*move*-task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html). There is also an example how to rename a set of files (last examples).

Comment: Danke! I'm using the move-task. See OscarRyz' answer.