# How to create a function or script in ant file?

Tags: function, ant

in my ant script I want to perform a piece of code twice. Exactly the same code. 
So I was thinking, is there any way how to create a function call in ant?

thanks,
O.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ant there are macros.

See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html

Comment: is there any way to include a xml file to a build ant file?

Comment: What would be that xml file? Some other build.xml file? If that's the case, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html

Comment: You could go one better and package your reusable ANT logic as an antlib. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643191/how-to-manage-a-common-ant-build-script-across-multiple-project-build-jobs-on-je/15647898#15647898