# Is it possible to generate the file 'build.xml' from the command line in Ant?

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

I am looking to script my build process. Currently I am able to build the `build.xml` file manually, and then run the following command to create the [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file:

```
    system("ant -f ~/build.xml")
```

I would like to rebuild my `build.xml` file every time I run this script so that I ensure all changes are in the `build.xml` file. Is there an [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) command I can run to build this build.xml file?

For reference, I am using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) currently to create my build.xml file.

Comment: Is this an Itellij question? One of the main reasons people favour ANT is because it gives them complete control over their build process. Maven on the other hand is designed to avoid writing build logic, instead relying on a standard build lifecycle, customized using plugins. Check it out an option before writing your own build tool. Worst case you learn a new tech :-)

Comment: Thanks Mark,  I will look into this tomorrow as soon as I can discuss switching to maven with my project manager

Answer (score 0):

There are other common ways to customize your build in Ant. Like:

- Introducing properties (possibly excluded to the `build.properties` file) and
- [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) wherever feasible.

These should cover most of the use cases in Ant.

For the more sophisticated stuff, you can even go for more logic using [`ant-contrib` tasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html).

As an alternative:

- If you'd still like to stick with generation of the custom `build.xml` file every time, you could go for some [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) transformation where you would do so. But that is not a common practice, I'd say. Or
- go for [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), as suggested in the comment or even
- go for [Grails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29)

However, to help you choose the fitting solution, you should tell us some more details on the `build.xml` changes you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Peter for this response.  I am unable to make any changes today and won't be able to touch the code until tomorrow.  The project manager suggested ant over maven when beginning the project, however if maven is a more useful tool he may be persuaded otherwise.  I will discuss this with him tomorrow and if it is not an option I will use properties in the build xml.  I was already considering doing that but didn't want to follow down that path if there was already a technique using ant.

Comment: You make no mention of macrodefs and ANT libs... In my experience these are far more useful for writing repeatable and re-usable logic. And I must respectfully disagree with your recommendation to use ant-contrib, when ANT needs scripting then that is the time to embed a scripting language (See script task).

Comment: Antlib example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643191/how-to-manage-a-common-ant-build-script-across-multiple-project-build-jobs-on-je/15647898#15647898

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I need.  Sorry I see that you commented on this under my original post and I missed it.  I will def. take a look at this as well today, thanks Mark