# How do you organize ant macrodefs used by multiple projects?

Tags: ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

I would like each of my Git repositories to have their own build.xml file, but avoid having to copy paste a lot of macrodefs used by the different build scripts.

What would be the best way to organize this?

Adding the ant macrodefs to a seperate Git repository and make them available for all the build projects on my Jenkins server? 
Adding them for instance to a directory of the Ant installation folder?

Does anybody have some experience with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same. I feel strongly that every project should be stand-alone and not depend on another source code repository. To achieve this I package my common macrodef's as an  [ANTLib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html). These are simply jar files that can be imported into the ANT build like other 3rd party tasks.

The following answer explains how to create an antlib:

- [How to manage a common ant build script across multiple project build jobs on jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643191/how-to-manage-a-common-ant-build-script-across-multiple-project-build-jobs-on-je/15647898#15647898)

The really big advantage of this approach is when you save the ANTlib jar in a versioned repository like Nexus. I use [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage my dependencies and this allows my common build logic to be versioned, enabling me to safely change logic without breaking older builds. When you think about it this is the same kind of workflow implemented by Maven (which also downloads plugins).