# Share ant macros

Tags: macros, ant, ivy

Can I share ant macros between projects in repository (maven repository)?
I use ivy to manage dependecies and share jars between projects, and I would like to share ant macros in the same way. But I need to import ant file after resolve and it is not possible.

So how to share ant macros between many similar projects?

Answer (score 1):

Package the macros as an [ANTlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html). These are jars that can be downloaded by Ivy just like any other ANT task depedency

See:

- [How to manage a common ant build script across multiple project build jobs on jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643191/how-to-manage-a-common-ant-build-script-across-multiple-project-build-jobs-on-je/15647898#15647898)