# Getting fileset dir value from ant to groovy

Tags: ant, groovy

I would like to ask a question related to ant task written in groovy.

I have following task definition:

```
   <mytask value1="test1" value2="test2">
     <fileset dir="." />
   </mytask>
```

Is there any way to read the **dir** value inside the groovy? I have no problem reading value1 and value2, but struggling with the fileset dir value.

I want to list all files and catalogs inside written directory, but can't read the path.

Would appreciate any help. Thx

Comment: Could you provide a better example?

Comment: Answering the question I think you're asking: This example demonstrates how the groovy ant task can reference filesets and dirsets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990723/how-to-rename-n-files-and-n-folders-with-ant/13998196#13998196